# 一定時間の無操作でスクリーンセーバーを起動する設計

Tags: swift, ios

iOSでswiftを使ってiPadアプリの開発をしております。

やりたいことは、
「一定時間の無操作でスクリーンセーバーを起動する」
なのですが、「一定時間の無操作の検出」をどのような設計で
実現するか悩んでおります。

スクリーンセーバーなので、どの画面でも無操作が一定時間続いたら、起動させないといけません。そのため、操作がされたという情報をどの画面でも取得しないといけませんが、全ての画面で操作をチェックする処理を組み込むというのは現実的ではないため、何かいい方法がないかと悩んでおります。

どういう設計が良いのかアドバイス等頂けないでしょうか。
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: オイラならスクリーンセーバーが動いて電池が減るより電池セーバーのほうが嬉しいです。

Comment: 私ならディスプレイオフ（iPadのデフォルトの挙動）じゃなくて、本当にスクリーンセイバーが必要なのか、スクリーンセイバーが必要な理由を確認しますねー

Answer (score 1):

操作がされたら、一定時間用の変数に値をセットします。例えば１０とか。
で１秒間隔のタイマー等でその値をデクリメントし、その値が０以下になったらスクリーンセイバー起動でどうでしょうか？

Comment: スクリーンセーバーなので、どの画面でも無操作が一定時間続いたら、起動させないといけません。このため、操作がされたという情報をどの画面でも取得しないといけません。全ての画面で操作をチェックする処理を組み込むというのは現実的ではないため、何かいい方法がないかと悩んでおります。

Comment: すべての画面というのは何ページぐらいあるのでしょうか？タッチイベントで処理はできませんか？https://qiita.com/Kyome/items/d86cefa9dbd7bd2d7cf0

Comment: 全ての画面は３０くらいです。このため、全ての画面でタッチイベントを取るのは大変なので、別の解決策を探しております。

Comment: これは参考になりませんか？https://nekokichi2yos2.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/10/26/115749

Comment: UIWindowのhitTestを使うことで、思っていたことが出来るようになりました。